# spring boot health check does not show db status

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

On  below line,

```
return Health.up().build()
```

I get only `{"status" : "UP"}`

I want to see the status of DB.
here is my properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=test
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.defaults.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false

endpoints.health.sensitive: false
endpoints.health.enabled.sensitive=false
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

what did i miss ? :(